# bootstrap panel-collapse show hide div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have following div to show/hide data

```
<div id="show-form-bank" class="panel-collapse collapse" >
    ...data to show
    </div>
```

when page load, div is closed, here no problem, when i click on update button its showing/display div thats also no problem, problem is when i click again on another update button its going closed, i want something is, if div is open and when i click again in update button then it will not close. it will close only if it open.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="editproduct(product_num)"class="btn-update" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#show-form-bank">Update</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="editproduct(product_num)"class="btn-update" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#show-form-bank">Update</a>
<a href="#" ng-click="editproduct(product_num)"class="btn-update" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#show-form-bank">Update</a>
.....
```